# YoloV5 Webcam-Stream on Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, real-time, webcam, yolov5

I am using Yolov5 and Google Colab for custom object detection.
Is it possible to access my local webcam in google colab to detect objects in real-time using custom weights in yolov5?
I can open my webcam and live-stream a video but detecting on that stream doesn't work yet.
Thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolov3-pytorch-streaming-on-google-colab-16f4fe72e7b) to accomplish object detection using YOLOv3 on google collab. It should be analogous for YOLOv5.

Comment: @PawełBęza This does not work anymore as we get the error `No module named utils.utils`